# What's the time signature for "Son of Flynn" and "Recognizer" in the TRON: Legacy Soundtrack by Daft Punk?

Tags: time-signatures, analysis, meter, motif

What's the time signature for ["Son of Flynn"](https://youtu.be/fsHz2DU7b7s) and ["Recognizer"](https://youtu.be/iDtMDlyS7x8) in the TRON: Legacy Soundtrack by Daft Punk?

It seems to me that "Son of Flynn" is clearly in a mixed meter: 3/8 and 5/8 -- but I'm not sure. "Recognizer" has a common theme and meter with the strings as in "Son of Flynn" that suggests 3/8 and 5/8 mixed meter, but the emphasis on these beats is less than in "Son of Flynn". At 1:48 in "Recognizer", the pace/rhythm changes. The brass and woodwinds seems to go with a 4/4 time signature.

**What's going on here with these two tracks in terms of the time signature?**

Answer (score 1):

Recognizer seems to be 4/4 throughout.

The fast notes in Son of Flynn are in groups of 6+6+4=16 so they can be viewed as 16th notes in a 4/4 bar; this isn't the only way to think about it though.